# Open Task manager and handle its multiple tabs using Java code

Tags: java

I want to open Task Manager and click on its tabs like 'Process','Performance','App history', etc. by using core java only.

Tried to begin with

```
public class Desktop1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"Taskmgr.exe");
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Taskmgr.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: If you are using a batch file to launch it then right click on it and "Run As Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. The simplest way is mentioned by @mkane in his comment. Programatically, this could be achieved in the following way: 
Add following dependency to your application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vnetpublishing.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>super-user-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can make your class extend `SuperUserApplication` class and override its `run()` as:

```
public int run(String[] strings) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"Taskmgr.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now call static `run(...)` of class `SU` passing in the instance of the class extending `SuperUserApplication`. Here is a complete example for your reference:

```
public class Main extends SuperUserApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SU.run(new Main(), args);
    }

//    @Override
    public int run(String[] strings) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"Taskmgr.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting warning in the console, WARNING: Elevating an application with administrator privileges from a network or removable drive may fail.